# Is "stands and strides toward..." a contradiction?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

(Tom is hiding behind a table flipped on its side. He's got a gun. He's hiding from a man who's shooting at him.) Then -

Suddenly Tom stands and strides toward the gunman, firing his gun at him.

Is "stands and strides toward..." contradictive?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not a contradiction.  I understand your question to mean *can a person be standing and striding at the same time*.  The answer to that question is no but it is more often the case that the word **and** is interpreted as **and then**.

When you encounter *and* as you have used it, the context creates a timeline.

> Suddenly Tom stands and [then] strides....

Comment: +1. Now, I'll lie down and go to sleep.

Comment: I'll sit down, read my book, and drink a cup of tea.

Comment: _Stands up and strides..._ might make the sequence of events clearer, since _stands_ can mean either _rises to his feet_ or _stands still_.